# Does Type Erasure occur when inheriting a generic class with a specified Type?

Tags: java, generics

When I have a field of `List<Foo>`, it will become just `List` at compile time thanks to type erasure.

But what happens if I use

```
class FooList extends List<Foo>
```

?
Is my `FooList` a List of `Foo` or a List of `Object` at compile time?

Comment: What would the observable difference be?

Comment: It's a `FooList` at compile time

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. `FooList` has no type parameters, so there is nothing to be erased. The class metadata will of course preserve all the interfaces it extends (with the types specified there). Maybe we can better answer this question if you show some sample code of what you want to achieve (i.e. the "observable difference").

Comment: @Thilo I am currently not in reach of a example. I've read that Generics will box primitive types and also cast at runtime, which may be a performance loss if you handle a lot of data. If my class `extends GenericClass<Type>`, i should not worry about the "background casting" anymore?

Comment: @Raildex: That seems to be a different question. But the generic types have no runtime impact at all. The equivalent non-generic, explicitly cast, explicitly boxed code would behave exactly the same. If you want to put a primitive in a List, you need to box it either way (or use a specialized IntList or such).

Answer (score 0):

Is important to take care about some points:

1. A class can't `extends` from List because it's a interface, you should `implements` in this case.
2. After build project your bytecode (.class file) should be like this: `public abstract class FooList implements List<Foo>` , so it's a simple list of Foo.
3. Be careful about this approach, look this peace of code using your FooList and using a simple List:

   public class Main {

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      //works
      List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();

      //don't work
      FooList fooList = new ArrayList<>();
      FooList fooList2 = new ArrayList();

      //work, but not necessary
      FooList fooList3 = new FooList() {
          //implement all method from List interface
      };
   }
   ```

   }